# What exactly is hydrolysis reaction in organic chemistry?What mechanism does it follow?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, hydrolysis

According to my study material:

> Hydrolysis is a special type of nucleophilic substitution ($\mathrm{S_N1}$) where water acts as both nucleophile and a solvent molecule.

Is this definition correct? If so how to solve the following problem (picked up from my textbook exercise which has no solution)?

> When alkyl bromides (listed here) were subjected to hydrolysis in a
>   mixture of ethanol and water ($80\ \%\ \ce{C2H5OH} / 20~\%\ \ce{H2O}$)
>   at $55~\mathrm{^\circ C}$ the rates of reaction showed the following order:
>   $\ce{(CH3)3CBr} > \ce{CH3Br} > \ce{CH3CH2Br} > \ce{(CH3)2CHBr}$.
>
> Provide an explaination for this order of reactivity.

But my doubt is how is this order $\ce{(CH3)3CBr} > \ce{CH3Br} > \ce{CH3CH2Br} > \ce{(CH3)2CHBr}$ possible?

I mean I know the first compound will form a tertiary carbocation. That is okay for $\mathrm{S_N1}$ but how will the second compound undergo $\mathrm{S_N1}$ (because methyl carbocation is very unstable)? Moreover if really $\mathrm{S_N1}$ is taking place the fourth compound should form a more stable carbocation compared to the third compound. These things are confusing me. Is hydrolysis really $\mathrm{S_N1}$ or something else?

According to me the order should have been $(1)>(4)>(3)>(2)$.

Comment: Do you call it a hydrolysis reaction? ... Because I just call it a substitution reaction...

Comment: @DHMO I stated what my textbook and study material wrote.I did'nt make up the definitions myself.See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solvolysis

Comment: Hydrolysis is not necessarily SN1, it can also refer to a SN2 process (especially if there is OH-). Or it can be any process really. There are many different ways of hydrolysing esters, for example. However, in this particular case, it is weird. I would expect only SN1 reactivity under the stated conditions, so I don't know why MeBr is so high up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your textbook is almost correct. Here is the corrected version of its statement:

> Hydrolysis is a special type of nucleophilic substitution where water acts as both nucleophile and a solvent molecule.

Note me omitting the $\mathrm{S_N1}$ part. This is because a hydrolysis mechanism can be *any* nucleophilic substitution, whether $\mathrm{S_N1, S_N2, S_N}$ for heavy atoms or $\mathrm{S_NAr}$.

That also explains the given order of reactivity. *tert*-Butyl bromide is very fast at $\mathrm{S_N1}$ reactions. Bromomethane very rapidly undergoes $\mathrm{S_N2}$ reactions. The other two are in-between with bromoethane being just a tad better at $\mathrm{S_N2}$ reactions than 2-bromopropane is at $\mathrm{S_N1}$ reactions.

($\mathrm{S_N1}$ is preferred in 2-bromopropane as the solvent is polar protic and it can stabilize the intermediate carbocation well)

Comment: By the extension of your definition: In the solvolysis definition in Wikipedia too should the $\mathrm{S_N1}$ be removed? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solvolysis

Comment: @ZOZ Yes.$%MathJax comments hurray!$

Comment: Morever,I cannot understand how can water in this case act as nucleophile in 20 percent ethanol.Water is considered to be a weak nuceophile.Can it really initiate a $\mathrm{S_N2}$ ?

Comment: @ZOZ Water isn’t *that* weak a nucleophile, tbh.

Comment: Well by that logic if it were 80 % ethanol and 20 % water would ethanol have acted as the nucleophile? I mean the ethyl group exerts a $+I$ effect on the O atom.So would ethanol be nucleophile in that case? @Jan

Comment: @ZOZ But ethanol is bulkier, allowing water to be a kinetically better nucleophile.

Comment: Thank you for clearing the doubt.I was really confused with that Wikipedia definition.Maybe I should edit that Wiki page :-P.